# Which page is run very first in laravel application when a project is execute

Tags: laravel, caching, browser-cache

I Want to know that if we execute a laravel project then which page is run very first. Which page is call first

Comment: `/public/index.php` See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/lifecycle

Comment: The entry point for all requests to a Laravel application is the public/index.php file. All requests are directed to this file by your web server (Apache / Nginx) configuration. The index.php file doesn't contain much code. Rather, it is a starting point for loading the rest of the framework.

The index.php file loads the Composer generated autoloader definition, and then retrieves an instance of the Laravel application from bootstrap/app.php script. The first action taken by Laravel itself is to create an instance of the application / service container.

Answer (score 0):

what ever in your route with /

```
Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
```